# Is there an existing library to parse Wikpedia tables from dump?

Tags: python, xml-parsing, extract, wikipedia

I need to extract the data from tables in a wiki dump in a somewhat convenient form, e.g. a list of lists. However, due to the format of the dump it looks sort of tricky. I am aware of the [WikiExtractor](https://github.com/attardi/wikiextractor), which is useful for getting clean text from a dump, but it drops tables altogether. Is there a parser that would get me conveniently readable tables in a same way?

Comment: Have you checked here: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page

Comment: @joelgoldstick, I did look at the [parser list page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers), and I have looked into some of them, and I am yet to find the one that fits my needs (XML dumps, one I can use - Python or standalone). Some of them, e.g. DizzyLogic, are not even accessible. That's why I decided to ask if anyone already used one of the parsers that can represent the tables neatly. API does not reall help since it has nothing to do with XML dumps.

Answer (score 0):

I did not manage to find a good way to parse Wikipedia tables from XML dumps. However, there seem to be some ways to do so using HTML parsers, e.g. [wikitables](http://wikitables.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#wikitables) parser. This would require a lot of scraping unless you need to analyze only the tables from specific pages. However, it seems possible to do it offline as it seems HTML Wiki dumps are about to resume ([dumps](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/htmldumps/dumps/), [phabricator task](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T17017))